# Why is my toolbox empty? (SolidWorks 2021)

Tags: solidworks, cad, tools

If I open SolidWorks and go to the toolbox, it only shows 1 map named 'Favorites'. The toolbox as well as the 'Favorites' map are empty. If I click to configure it opens a window as shown in the picture. How can I set up this toolbox for all the bolts, nuts etc?  [image]

Thanks!

Comment: How was Toolbox installed? Was it from an original, licensed package or "other" source?

Comment: ...go through the "steps below" - the answer to your question is literally in the screenshot. Click those links in order to define the content of your toolbox according to your needs.